# encipher github

Tags: windows, git, github

I don't want people to be able to find all of my code just by doing a google search (I'm using github for just myself) for the time being.

Is there a way to run a rot13 or anything as crude on all my files to commit before each commit?

I'm thinking of a shell/bat script (I'm on Windows) that goes through an entire dir, copys all the files to another folder, then rot13 the whole thing, then commit the new subfolder.

Anyone know if this can be done, or is done, or is there any other technique?

Comment: Your username wouldn't happen to be the same on git, would it? =)

Comment: It might be possible, but it is going to really mess with git's ability to track changes and history, etc.

Comment: Maybe you should look into using bitbucket, which now supports git and offers free private repos.

Comment: **Stop using GitHub**, obviously. Any machine can host a git repository. Use of Git for your VCS does *not* require the use of GitHub for remote hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a commit hook, if Github supports them

But it sounds like Github is the wrong tool for you. They explicitly only allow public repositories (for free), so if they caught you trying to make a quasi-private repo, they'd likely ban you.

However, you can put Git repos anywhere with ssh access, and there are even tools (like gitosis or gitolite) to allow others to access it. You can use gitweb or similar to see the repo over HTTP, and replicate most of the non-social features of Github - and it's all under your control so you don't have to play any tricks. If you don't want search engines, just exclude them with robots.txt

Comment: I need to be able to use it on windows though, preferably with a tool similar to git gui

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use GitHub specifically, and your budget allows you to spend an extra $7 a month, you could opt for a "Micro" subscription plan, their cheapest offering that permits a truly private Git repo. <del>You only get one private repo, but</del> You get *5* private repos, and you can still have unlimited public repos. [They have other plans as well.](https://github.com/plans)